# The upper data series won't plot a line

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm planning to plot two series of data on a single graph. The bottom axis is the year. I suspect that they wont plot the upper series because both don't share the same intervals. 2-year intervals for upper and 1-year intervals for bottom. The effect I'm looking is to just connect the dots of the upper series. How do I achieve that?

[image: graph]

Comment: You say "I suspect..." have you tried?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/884406/a-line-chart-may-plot-gaps-in-lines-when-the-data-range-contains-blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mess with your data. In the simple data range below, there are some blank cells in the range, which are plotted as gaps in the top chart below. Select the chart and click Select Data on the Chart Tools > Design ribbon tab, and click the Hidden and Empty Cells button on the bottom left corner of the dialog. Check Connect Data Points With Line, and click OK twice to return to your chart. The data points separated by empty cells will now be connected by lines (bottom chart).

[image]

Comment: That's a much simpler way of doing it! Thank you!